# Can I override bootstrap's defaults in a single css selector?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to get rid of `outlines` in Firefox, however they're pointed more deeply than my `style.css` in `bootstrap3.css` so I need to update them all.

I've tried the following:

```
<link href="{{ URL::to('home_assets/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<link href="{{ URL::to('home_assets/css/style.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
```

Example below didn't work because Bootstrap 3 points more deeply.

```
//bootstrap
a.carousel-control 
{
    outline: thin dotted;
}

//my css
body {
    outline: none !important;
}

Result: a.carousel-control has thin dotted outline.
```

I need to do something like to remote outline. (and it works)

```
a.carousel-control 
{
    outline: none;
}
```

The problem is, then I need to point everything in markup deeply so it overrides bootstrap. I need to encapsulate most of Bootstrap's css.

Is there a functionality like this in CSS, so I can manage them from a single place?

```
body {
    outline: none !override-previous; //pseudo
}
```

Any hacks or tricks to manage them in a single place? (no javascript, css expressions are okay though)

Ps. I need this for my dev environment because I keep outlines as default on production to help blind users. They're annoying for me, though.

Comment: What would a hypothetical `!override-previous` mean? What does "previous" refer to?

Comment: Override every "outline" previously mentioned to be overridden with current one, regardless of the depth of css selectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
*{
outline: none !important;
}
```

and please add this after your bootstrap.css file so that it'll override.

Comment: I've added this in my style.css and it worked. Why does "*" selector override more in-depths selectors like "a.something > ul.somethingelse { outline: thin dotted; } ?

Comment: Glad it worked. yup, that means select all the elements in that page or DOM. If this worked, you need to click on "checkbox" near my answer to select as chosen. good luck.

Comment: So it always overrides previously defined attributes? (When it's defined at bottom.)

Comment: Yes it does. You can refer to this link to know more about CSS, its free: http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/htmlcss-tutorials/the-best-way-to-learn-css-2/